# Validation Rule giving me a huge headache

Tags: formula, validation, picklist

Basically I need a validation rule to say

IF field “HasOptedOutOfEmail” is unchecked, and mailing country = Canada, then field Canada_Email_Consent__c needs to be Updated. However the record shouldnt be saved if the picklsit value for Canada_Email_Consent__c = No-Consent, the record should only be saved if picklist contains the word "Yes"

IF field “HasOptedOutOfEmail” is unchecked, and mailing country  <> Canada, then field Canada_Email_Consent__c doesn’t need  to be completed, and the record can be saved

Field name: HasOptedOutOfEmail
Datatype : Checkbox

Field name:  Canada_Email_Consent__c
Datatype : Picklist

Hoping you guys can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Several attempts, the formula is

AND( 
ISCHANGED(HasOptedOutOfEmail), 
HasOptedOutOfEmail = false, 
MailingCountry = 'Canada', 
ISPICKVAL(Canada_Email_Consent__c, 'No-Consent') 
)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
If (
    And (
        HasOptedOutOfEmail = false,
        MailingCountry = 'Canada',
        IsPickVal(Canada_Email_Consent__c, '')
    ),
    true,
    false
)
```

Comment: Canada_Email_Consent__c is a picklist value , so i am getting an error on your validation

Comment: I've updated my answer to use IsPickVal

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
IF(
    AND(HasOptedOutOfEmail = false, Mailing_Country__c = 'Canada'),
    IF(
        ISPICKVAL(Canada_Email_Consent__c, 'No-Consent'),
        true,
        ISBLANK(TEXT(Canada_Email_Consent__c))
    ),
    false
)
```

This basically says:

If `HasOptedOutOfEmail` is unchecked and `Mailing_Country__c` is Canada, then check `Canada_Email_Consent__c`. If `Canada_Email_Consent__c` is 'No-Consent', then return true. Otherwise, check if `Canada_Email_Consent__c` is blank. When checking if `Canada_Email_Consent__c` is blank, it converts it to text first (which is required for a picklist) and then evaulates if it is blank. If it is blank, it returns true, otherwise it returns false.

Check out [`IF()`](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#IF), [`AND()`](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#AND), [`ISPICKVAL()`](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#ISPICKVAL), [`ISBLANK()`](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#ISBLANK), and [`TEXT()`](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#TEXT) for more details.

Comment: @ Jess Altman, Canada_Email_Consent__c is a picklist value , so i am getting an error on your validation

Comment: Alright. Let me update my answer. I didn't realize it was a picklist.

Comment: ( i applogise i thought i put it in my criteria , however i put put data type: data doh ! ) in the validation is it possible to say if HasOptedOutOfEmail  unchecked then Canada_Email_Consent__c cant be picklist value "No-Consent"

Comment: That is a bit different from what you originally asked @user8746. Can you update your original question to be as specific as possible? What you are looking to do seems to be changing as we go.

Comment: i have updated with all relevant changes

Comment: I have updated my answer again @user8746. If this helps, feel free to give an upvote and mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

AND(NOT(HasOptedOutOfEmail), Mailing Country = Canada, NOT(ISPICKVAL(Canada_Email_Consent__c, "Yes")))